# How to select nested colors from theme in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm creating a style to use within a Button, but I'm unsure on how to select a nested style from my theme. Here is my style and theme:

```
const buttonStyle: SxProps<Theme> = {
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: 'backgroundAlert', // workaround
  },

};

export const darkTheme = createTheme(themeOptions, {
  palette: {
    mode: 'dark',
    background: {
      default: '#0B0E16',
      paper: '#1D1F2B',
      alert: '#373B38' // I want to use this property
    },
    backgroundAlert: '#373B38', // workaround
  },
});
```

I'm using `backgroundAlert` as a work around because i don't know how to select `alert` from `background.alert` since it's nested. I couldnt find anything in the docs - does anyone know the syntax to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below worked for me.

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles'; 

const ButtonStyle = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: darkTheme.palette.background.alert,
  },
}));

<ButtonStyle variant="contained">Your Button</ButtonStyle>
```